# Phonegap - Read sub-directories?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I am working with Phonegap / Cordova 2.2

I am trying to read the contents of a sub-directory but can not figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {

var tmpPath = "dir1/dir2/";

fileSystem.root.getDirectory(tmpPath, {create: false, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess, fail);           
}


function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {

// Get a directory reader
var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

// Get a list of all the entries in the directory
directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);
}
```

If I only fetch a single directory path then it works, if I try to fetch a path with two directories it fails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which part fails? The `getDirectory` call or the `readEntries` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could do it like this:

```
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var tmpPath = filesystem.root.fullPath + "/dir1/dir2";
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(tmpPath, getDirSuccess, fail);           
}
```

But I'm curious why the code you showed didn't work. What platform are you testing on?

Comment: I am working on Android. I fixed the problem... Stupid mistake on my part. The second folder did not exist and I thought it would generate the folder but I had "create: false" I changed it to "create: true" and all is well. Sorry! Hope this thread helps someone else to avoid the same mistake.    Also Simon I read a lot of your blogs and help posts about PhoneGap, great contributor !

Comment: Okay, cool good to know. I was just checking to see if I needed to go fix a bug on the Android side.